# postgresql copy with schema support

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

I'm trying to load some data from CSV using the postgresql COPY command. The trick is that I'd like to implement multi-tenancy on a userid (which is contained in the CSV). Is there an easy way to tell the postgres copy command to filter based on this userid when loading the csv?

i.e. all rows with userid=x go to schema=x, rows with userid=y go to schema=y.

Comment: what about creating a partitioned table, where the base table delegates inserts based on the userID into the different target tables?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way of doing this with just the COPY command, but you could copy all your data into a master table, and then put together a simple PL/PGSQL function that does this for you.  Something like this -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.spike()
    RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        user_id integer;
        destination_schema text;
    BEGIN
        FOR user_id IN SELECT userid FROM master_table GROUP BY userid LOOP
            CASE user_id
            WHEN 1 THEN
                destination_schema := 'foo';
            WHEN 2 THEN
                destination_schema := 'bar';
            ELSE
                destination_schema := 'baz';
            END CASE;


            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| destination_schema ||'.my_table SELECT * FROM master_table WHERE userid=$1' USING user_id;
            -- EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM master_table WHERE userid=$1' USING user_id;

        END LOOP;

            TRUNCATE TABLE master_table;

        RETURN;
    END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

This gets all unique user_ids from the master_table, uses a CASE statement to determine the destination schema, and then executes an INSERT SELECT to move rows, and finally deletes the moved rows.

Comment: All this function is doing is a series of INSERT SELECTS.  Its just automating the process of moving the rows and deleting them from the master table.

Comment: this would work, but unfortunately this import has to run at regular intervals (every 5 minutes or so), and I feel like this is just going to keep my db too busy

Comment: @OrenMazor you don't have many other options...  And this can run quite fast.  How many users/schemas and rows do you have per run?

Comment: lets say 100k users with a total of around 100k rows every 5 minutes.

Comment: I've optimized this function with a single TRUNCATE instead of a DELETE every iteration.  But..100k users, does that mean you're going to have 100k tables? That is alot, though I don't know what postgres's limit is on number of tables...  Have you considered keeping everything in a master table and creating views to fetch out data for each user? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: From the OP's description, 100k *schemas*. I imagine there will be quite a lot more than 100k tables.

Comment: @Catcall, actually in this case, there would be only one table segmented across these schemas

Comment: So I'm going to assume we are going to be iterating over this loop ~100k times, but the INSERT SELECT done each time would be for a relatively few number of rows.  With an index on `userid`, that should be very very fast.  Each iteration would have to take more than 3ms to make this function fun longer than 5min, but I would expect it to take less than that. Even factoring in the time to do the COPY, you should still come in under 5min.  However, there may be some other solution - some different schema design or client changes that make this a non issue.  Hard to say without knowing intent.

Comment: The other problem is that a case with that many possibilities will not be feasible. You would probably want to replace that with a select from some table that can match a `userid` with their schema name.  This would add time, but not too much if you index the `userid` column on that table.

Comment: the more I think about this, the more I realize this is basically my only option. the nice thing is that the schemas would really just map to the IDs available in each row, so I dont really need a lookup for them.